# Knockout get input value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I already searched the web and tried to read the manual, but failed to find an answer for my problem

I have this editable grid with knockout js:

http://jsfiddle.net/peterf/8FMPc/light/

```
<input type="text" class="edit" data-bind="value: name.editValue, visible: $root.isItemEditing($data)"  />
<label class="read" data-bind="text: name, visible: !$root.isItemEditing($data)" />
```

What I want to do is, after clicking the button "Add new Fruit" and inserting the Fruit Name, to get the inserted value by console from web developer tools/ code.

English is not my native language; please excuse typing errors.

Comment: There is a `fruit` variable inside the `applyFruit` method - it has the values you've added.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for?

http://jsfiddle.net/8FMPc/305/

```
self.applyFruit = function (fruit) {
        //  commit the edit transaction
        self.editTransaction.notifySubscribers(null, "commit");
        console.log(fruit.name());
        //  hides the edit fields
        self.editingItem(null);
    };
```